# Visual Studio 2010 Extensão para Outline

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Sei que existem extensões para o Visual Studio 2010 que exibe outline específicas para cada ambiente: C#, css/javscritp e HMTL?

Existem alguma solução em uma única extensão? Ou tenho de conformar e instalar várias extensões para um mesmo proposito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente você terá de instalar varias extensões para o mesmo propósito, pois cada uma foi construída unica e exclusivamente para a linguagem especifica.

Comment: Suspeitava desde o princípio! kkkk Muito obrigado valeu a ajuda.

Comment: @JotaJotaJota tive o mesmo problema tempos atras, infelizmente.

Comment: Sem querer abusar, mas abusando, achei para C# (CSharpOutline) e Javascritp/Css (JavaScript & CSS Outlining).  E para HTML você indica algum?

Comment: @JotaJotaJota não lembro de nenhuma agora, mas vou ver aqui e ja te falo.

Comment: Fico agradecido se puder quebrar este galho, deve ser lerdeza minha, mas não achei.